# how do i send one message to multiple emails in strings

Tags: php, string, email, send

i have a string like:

```
  $email = 'xyz@email.com,abc@email.Com,and others@email.com'; 
AND
  $msg = 'SEND these to each email above thanks';
```

in my achievement i want to be able to send text in the $msg as an email message to each email in $email example:

```
  $to = 'xyz@email.com';
  $msg = 'SEND these to each email above thanks';
  $to = 'abc@email.com';
  $msg = 'SEND these to each email above thanks';
   $to = 'others@email.com';
  $msg = 'SEND these to each email above thanks';



  foreach($email as $email)
  {
  $to = $email["to"];


   $subject = 'the subject';
   $message = '$msg';
   $headers = 'is this really? ';
   mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);

   }
```

big thanks for your impact in my soluction

Comment: for a start `$email` is not an array, use `explode()` to make it one.

Comment: @nogad
 i dont really get your idea do you have any code example?

Answer (score 0):

Try splitting the emails string and for each email execute the code that sends the mail

```
<?php

$emails = 'email1@example.com,email2@example.com';
$emailsSplitted = explode(',', $emails);

foreach ($emailsSplitted as $email) {
    // ...
    // use here the variable $email to send the message
}
```